# WP - Get depth of category's subcategories

Tags: wordpress, categories

In Wordpress, I'm looking to get the depth a category's subcategories.

Suppose I have a category 'grandparent' which has a subcategory 'parent' which in turn has a subcategory 'child'. How do I get to integer 2?

I suppose I could check if 'grandparent' has subcategories and if it does, check if they have subcategories, etc, until I hit 0. But that seems like a lot of unnecessary processing.

Isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: Which function you are using?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice blog post [here](http://www.devdevote.com/cms/wordpress-hacks/get_depth)  that shows you how to build a function that will get you the depth of a category but not only... check the page the function has more options.

EDIT: code here:

```
function get_depth($id = '', $depth = '', $i = 0) {
    global $wpdb;

    if($depth == '') {
        if(is_page()) {
            if($id == '') {
                global $post;
                $id = $post->ID;
            }
            $depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '".$id."'");
            return get_depth($id, $depth, $i);
        }
        elseif(is_category()) {
            if($id == '') {
                global $cat;
                $id = $cat;
            }
            $depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT parent FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = '".$id."'");
            return get_depth($id, $depth, $i);
        }
        elseif(is_single()) {
            if($id == '') {
                $category = get_the_category();
                $id = $category[0]->cat_ID;
            }
            $depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT parent FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = '".$id."'");
            return get_depth($id, $depth, $i);
        } 
    }
    elseif($depth == '0') {
        return $i;
    }
    elseif(is_single() || is_category()) {
        $depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT parent FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = '".$depth."'");
        $i++;
        return get_depth($id, $depth, $i);
    }
    elseif(is_page()) {
        $depth = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '".$depth."'");
        $i++;
        return get_depth($id, $depth, $i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $cat to be the category ID of 'grandparent':

```
$number_of_subcategories = count(get_categories("echo=0&cat=" . $cat));
```

May help?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. it returns 1 where it should return 2 - for a grandparent that has a child and a grandchild.

Comment: and it also returns 1 where it should return 0 - a category without any subcategories

Comment: Ah well, worth a shot.  I based it on the Wordpress Reference, which is occasionally a bit iffy.  Sorry I didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$args = array(
                'type'                     => 'post',
                'child_of'                 => 0,
                'parent'                   => 0,
                'orderby'                  => 'name',
                'order'                    => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'               => 1,
                'hierarchical'             => 0,
                'exclude'                  => '',
                'include'                  => '',
                'number'                   => '',
                'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                'pad_counts'               => false 
                );
                $cats = get_categories( $args );
                foreach( $cats as $cat) {
                    if($cat->parent == 0) {
                        $parent_cat = null;
                        $head = $cat->name;
                        $head_id = $cat->term_id;
                    }
                    echo "<ul><a class='parent-category' href=''>" . $head . "</a>";                                                    
                    wp_list_cats("sort_column=NAME&optioncount=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$head_id}&show_option_none=");
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks, but this outputs a list of categories, rather than returning the number of generations of subcategories.

Comment: so in this case you can only use by this way $number_of_subcategories = count(get_categories("echo=0&cat=" . $cat))-1; with respect to Owen 'Coves' Jone's answer